# What's more expensive: hot foil or blind emboss?

Tags: print-design, print-production, technique

Give a shared specification, which technique (blind emboss or hot foil) is more expensive?

- identical graphics
- same size of let's say 5 x 5 cm

As far as I know, hot foils aren't that expensive, so I'd place my bet on blind emboss to be pricier, since a second (negative) die is needed to be made.

Any thoughts/experiences? Thanks!

Comment: That is a great question to ask you printer of choice! :)

Comment: I would expect this has a lot to do with the quantity. For small runs, the die setup is probably going to be on par with the per-piece price, but for larger runs I expect the per-piece to dominate and then the setup cost is trivial.

Comment: @Vincent: I suspected that might be the answer, but sadly every printer I've asked so far gave a hugely different quote/explanation, so I wanted an outside view to have a clearer idea of how do they come to their numbers.

Comment: @Yorik I.e. Hot foil is cheaper in a smaller run and gets more expensive/on par with blind emboss as quantity grows? Makes sense. Too bad there's no way to draw the line what's more cost efficient (e.g. it's better to use hot foiling for a run of 500 or less, then it gets pricier than blind emboss) when every printer prices their setup time in an extremely different way (since their print setups/machines vary).